# How to get restaurant_name when clicking delete button to perform delete operation with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to perform a delete operation, to delete an item from user's favorites but am having a hard time figuring our how to retrieve restaurant_name.

In POSTMAN my delete operation url is {{baseUrl}}/favorites/restaurant_name/user_name
Currently I can retrieve the user_name of logged in user from session storage

I tried many ways to retrieve the restaurant_name.
One way I tried was to store it in the URL and tried to retrieve it from there but it did not work.
I also tried to store the restuarant_name in session storage when I click the button but that did not work either. The value for restaurant_name did not show up in session_storage.

[image: 1]

As u can see from the image bottom left hand corner, the restaurant_name can be retrieved in the URL. However when I try to console.log(restaurant_name) it says its undefined the first time as it has not gone to the URL with restaurant name yet (e.g localhost3000/favorites.html?restaurant_name=Astons). Afterwards going to the URL it is able to retrieve the restaurant_name from the URL.

This is my code for reference. Any help will be appreciated :)

Get Favorites

```
function getFavorites() {
    var response = "";
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    user_name = sessionStorage.getItem('user_name');
    request.open("GET", "https://abakandkansdjk.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/favorites/" + user_name, true);

    request.onload = function () {
        response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        console.log(response);


        var HTML = ""
        for (let i = 0; i < response.Count; i++) {
            console.log(response.Items[i].restaurant_name)



            HTML += '<div class="col-md-3 box " style="background-color: #debc99;">' +
                '<div class="card" style="margin:15px -5 20px -5; ">' +
                '<a class="card-block stretched-link" href="#"></a>' +
                '<img class="card-img-top" src="' + response.Items[i].image + '" style="margin-left: 1px;width: 220px; margin-top: -15px;"' +
                'alt="Card image cap">' +
                '<div class="card-body">' +
                '<h5 class="card-title"></h5>' +


                '<h4 style="margin-top: 0px; color:black">' + response.Items[i].restaurant_name + '</h4>' +
                '<span class="badge badge-secondary float-right"' +
                'style="background-color: #8d4843; margin-top: -5px;">Cuisine</span>' +
                '<a style="color: black; margin-top: -5px;" onclick="deleteFavorites(); sessionStorage.setItem("favRestaurant",' + response.Items[i].restaurant_name +');" href="favorites.html?restaurant_name=' + response.Items[i].restaurant_name + '"' + '><u>Delete</u></a>' +

                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +

                '</div>'





        }

        document.getElementById('favoritesList').innerHTML = HTML;
    };
    request.send();
}
```

Delete Favorites

```
function deleteFavorites() {
    var response = "";
    var user_name = sessionStorage.getItem("user_name")
    console.log(user_name)

    var alert1 = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item from your favourites? This is irreversible.");

    if (alert1 === true) {
        window.location.href="http://localhost:3000/favorites.html?restaurant_name=" + restaurant_name
        console.log(restaurant_name)
        var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        var restaurant_name = urlParams.get("restaurant_name");
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "https://aba3bajndc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/favorites/" + restaurant_name + "/" + user_name
        console.log("restaurant_name")
        request.open("DELETE", url, true);
        request.onload = function () {
            if (response.message == "favorites deleted") {
                alert('This restaurant has been deleted from favorites!');

            }
            else if (response.message != "favorites deleted") {
                alert('Unable to add to favorites, try again!');

            }
        }
        request.send();
    }
  
}
```

Comment: There's nothing AWS specific about this question. This is just a basic HTML/JavaScript question.

Comment: there's nothing postman specific in this question neither.

Answer (score 0):

I would change `onclick="deleteFavorites();` to:

```
onclick="deleteFavorites(response.Items[i].restaurant_name);
```

And change the `deleteFavorites` function signature to be:

```
function deleteFavorites(restaurant_name) {
```